# Troubles in writing data into TIFF file with GDAL

Tags: python, arcmap, gdal, geotiff-tiff

There are problems in my writing data into .tif file with GDAL module in python.
I want to extract data (numpy array) from a TIFF file and modify some of its values before saving it into a new one, with the new file functioning normally. I use following script:

```
tif = gdal.Open('data/pre_heilj_mean90_15.tif') #original tif file
imwidth = tif.RasterXSize
imheight = tif.RasterYSize
data = tif.ReadAsArray()
data[100][100] = 100 #modify value
data = data.astype(np.float32)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dataset = driver.Create('data/res.tif', imwidth, imheight, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.SetSpatialRef(tif.GetSpatialRef())
dataset.SetGeoTransform(tif.GetGeoTransform())
dataset.SetProjection(tif.GetProjection())
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
dataset.FlushCache()
dataset=None
data=None
tif=None
```

I am certain that data in original TIFF file is 2D and float32 type.
However, the new TIFF file (res.tif) is *all black* in ArcMap:
[res.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C8rQ.png)

Here is how the original TIFF file shows in ArcMap:
[original TIFF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHW3j.png)

And sizes of the two files differ a lot, original is 5287KB and the new one is 4633KB.
I want to know what goes wrong.

Comment: All-black in a 32-bit float TIFF is nothing unusual. You just need to compile statistics, is all.

Comment: But I'm not familiar with TIFF or python, what should I do specifically?

Comment: Computing raster statistics is a GIS function.

Comment: As you can see, ArcMAP is stretching the data range 406-806 into full grayscale from black to white. Adjust the same stretch for the other image. But it seems also that the source image has nodata=-3.4e38 but in the conversion the nodata flag gets dropped and those extremely small values are also interpreted to mean real data.